# XElement.XPathSelectElements returns no matching elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xslt

I'm having some trouble getting the extension methods in `System.Xml.XPath` to work for me. I'm using .NET 4.5 and VS 2012.

I've included a basic example of what I'm trying to do below (i.e. use the extension methods to use XPath to select XML-nodes). Expected results were sanity-checked using http://www.xpathtester.com/.

For each case, I get 0 elements returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Parse("<a><b /><b /><b><c id='1'/><c id='2' /></b></a>");
        ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a"); // I would expect 1 match
        ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b"); // I would expect 3 matches
        ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b/c"); // I would expect 2 matches
        ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b/c[@id='1']"); // I would expect 1 match
        ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b/c[@id='2']"); // I would expect 1 match
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ReportMatchingNodeCount(XElement root, string xpath)
    {
        int matches = root.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Count();
        Console.WriteLine(matches);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is the root element so your XPath is looking for `/a/a/b`

Try:

```
ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/b"); // I would expect 3 matches
ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/b/c"); // I would expect 2 matches
ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/b/c[@id='1']"); // I would expect 1 match
ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/b/c[@id='2']"); // I would expect 1 match
```

Returns: 3
2
1
1

Answer (score 2):

It happens because `XElement.Parse` returns `a` element as current node. Use `XDocument.Parse` instead.

Use this code, it provides the expected result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = XDocument.Parse("<a><b /><b /><b><c id='1'/><c id='2' /></b></a>");
    ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a"); // I would expect 1 match
    ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b"); // I would expect 3 matches
    ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b/c"); // I would expect 2 matches
    ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b/c[@id='1']"); // I would expect 1 match
    ReportMatchingNodeCount(root, "/a/b/c[@id='2']"); // I would expect 1 match
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void ReportMatchingNodeCount(XNode root, string xpath)
{
    int matches = root.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Count();
    Console.WriteLine(matches);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd drop the leading forward slash (/) from each of the queries.  You may also need to add an XML declaration to the beginning of your XML.  See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```